# What is the use of autoconnect flag in connect device method of BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect my android device to BLE device. I am using the following code to do it.

```
 mBluetoothGatt = mDevice.connectGatt(BaseApplication.getContext(), true, getInstance());
```

You can see the second parameter as true.In docs it is called as autoconnect flag. I can keep it true as well as false. What is the use of that flag ? Only thing that I have observed is that when I use autoconnect as true it connects for sure but with delay, if I use false it does not connect each time,sometime it does and sometime it does not.
Also I would like to know is this the correct way to connect a saved device each time ? or is it only after scanning for first time and there is some other way to do it ?
  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> You can see the second parameter as true.In docs it is called as
>   autoconnect flag. I can keep it true as well as false. What is the use
>   of that flag ?

whenever your remote device is become visible its automatically connected if is it true.

> Also I would like to know is this the correct way to connect a saved
>   device each time ?

The best way to connect save device You need to store the Bluetooth Device Address (AB:CD:EF:01:02:03) of the device in for example shared preferences or in a sqlite db. Then use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getRemoteDevice(java.lang.String) when you later restart the app to retrieve a BluetoothDevice object. Once you have the BluetoothDevice object you can use the connectGatt method as usual.

Comment: Yes I am keeping it in shared preferences.So what is the preferable way ? should I keep it true or false ?

Comment: you should keep true for any time if you want auto connect functionality.

Comment: ok thanks :) btw getRemoteDevice , how will it affect me if I am using device.connect each time and not getRemoteDevice with its address ?

Comment: this will not affect if you  request for each time.

Comment: @Pritish welcome !!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the question has already been answered in [Which correct flag of autoConnect in connectGatt of BLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156699/which-correct-flag-of-autoconnect-in-connectgatt-of-ble/40187086).

For your second question, see [Android save BLE device to reconnect after app close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476369/android-save-ble-device-to-reconnect-after-app-close/43482099#43482099).

Comment: Thanks :) You have answered many of my BLE related questions on SO :) thanks a lot for that :)